# My jQuery Ajax success function not working, not displaying output of the console and not validating form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've been toiling at this for some time. This survey is sending the data each time I click "submit", regardless of what I put in there.

I used to get the output and the (result.result == 1) message that's at the bottom when I checked all seven questions but now it just silently sends anything and everything and I receive it in my database without *any* output.

Even when I used to get the whole output, for the checkbox question (question 5) I would get the opposite console.log msg "Checkbox unchecked" when in reality it was checked, the rest of the console output was fine. And the output would *only* work if I had *all* seven checked. I have a contact form on this website with exactly the same method (jQuery, JSON, Ajax success function) it works well.

How can I fix this?

```
    <form id="survey" method="post" action="actions.php">
      <div id="survey-close-button" class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">

        <div class="popup-inner">

          <div id="question1">
            <p><label>1) What gender are you?</label></p>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="gender" value="female">Female<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="gender" value="other">Other
          </div>

          <div id="question2">
            <p><label>2) How old are you?</label></p>
            <select id="age" name="ageselect">
              <option value="0">Please select</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div id="question3">
            <p><label>3) English student for: </label></p>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="years" value="0-2">0-2years<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="years" value="2-5">2-5years<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="years" value="5-10">5-10years<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="years" value="allmylife">all my life<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="years" value="never studied">never studied
          </div>

          <div id="question4">
            <p><label>4) Experience with English abroad</label></p>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="abroad" value="less than a year">less than a year<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="abroad" value="1-3 years">1-3 years<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="abroad" value="3-6 years">3-6 years<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="abroad" value="6-10 years">6-10 years<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="abroad" value="all my life">all my life<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="abroad" value="never lived abroad">never lived abroad
          </div>

          <div id="question5">
            <p><label>5) How do you learn English? Choose all that apply</label></p>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="way[]" value="inperson">in-person course<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="way[]" value="privateteacher">private teacher<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="way[]" value="selflearner">self-learner<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="way[]" value="onlinecourse">online course<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="way[]" value="onlineteacher">onlineteacher<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="way[]" value="videogames">video games<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="way[]" value="other">other

          </div>

          <div id="question6">
            <p><label>6) How many foreign languages do you speak?</label></p>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="others" value="one">One<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="others" value="two">Two<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="others" value="three">I'm a polyglot

          </div>

          <div id="question7">
            <p><label>7) Where do you live?</label></p>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="country" value="Brazil">Brazil<br>
            <input type="radio" class="radios" name="country" value="Abroad">Abroad
          </div>
          <button id="submit_survey" type="submit" name="submitsurvey">Submit</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the jQuery code: Edited

```
<script>
    var selectElement = document.getElementById("age");
    if (selectElement !== undefined) {
        for (var agenum = 1; agenum <= 100; agenum++) {
            selectElement.add(new Option(agenum));
        }
    }

    var validForm = false;
    var input1 = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
    var input3 = $('input[name=years]:checked').val();
    var input4 = $('input[name=abroad]:checked').val();

    var input6 = $('input[name=others]:checked').val();
    var input7 = $('input[name=country]:checked').val();

    if (typeof input1 == "undefined" ||
        typeof input3 == "undefined" ||
        typeof input4 == "undefined" ||
        typeof input6 == "undefined" ||
        typeof input7 == "undefined") {

        console.log('Its Empty');
        validForm = false;
    }
    else {
        console.log(input1, input3, input4, input6, input7);
        validForm = true;
    }

    if (selectElement.value > 0) {
        validForm = true;
        console.log('good age');
    }

    if (selectElement.value == 0) {
        validForm = false;
        console.log('no age');
    }

    var check;
    check = $("#check").prop("checked");
    if(check) {
        console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
        validForm = true;
    }
    else {
        console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
        validForm = false;
    }

    $("#survey").submit(function(){
        return false;
    });

    $("#submit_survey").on("click", function(){

        var formData = $("#survey :input").serializeArray();

        formData[formData.length] = { name: "action", value: "submit_survey"};
        formData.push({});

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#survey").attr("action"),
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function(result){

                // If all is good do stuff
                if (result.result == 1) {
                    alert("Your survey has been submitted, thank you");
                    //$("#survey")[0].reset();
                }
                if (result.result == 2) {
                    alert("Please Try again");
                }

            } // Ajax, success function//
        }); // Ajax//

    }); // Submit on.click function//

</script>
```

Here is actions.php edited to the necessary parts:

```php
<?php
    require_once('./dbconn.php');

    $action = "";

    if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
        $action = $_POST["action"];

        if ($action == "submit_survey") {
            $export = Array();
            $gender = $_POST["gender"];

            $ageselect = $_POST["ageselect"];
            $years = $_POST["years"];
            $abroad = $_POST["abroad"];

            $way[] = $_POST["way"];
            $others = $_POST["others"];
            $country = $_POST["country"];

            $way = implode(' + ', $_POST['way']);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO survey (Radio_1, Age, Radio_3, Radio_4, Radio_5,
                   Radio_6, Radio_7)

            VALUES ('$gender', '$ageselect', '$years', '$abroad', '$way', '$others',
                   '$country')";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) === TRUE) {
                $export['result'] = "1";
            }
            else {
                $export['result'] = "2";
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($export);
    }
?>
```

Comment: That is a lot of HTML and code. Can you at least fix the indentation (that is, make it consistent)? - by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60730124/edit). Thanks in advance. (What text editor or IDE do you use? - I have some tips)

Comment: I dont see #checkbox being defined, $("#checkbox").prop("checked");

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Where is it breaking??

Comment: @PeterMortensen I edited the HTML, sorry. I'm using Komodo Edit 12 IDE

Comment: So why are you submitting the data to the server and doing the logic inside the success method of the call? Why is the validation not happening before you submit the form?

Comment: @NicoHaase I can't put it into techniques I'm afraid but I've tried line by line console.log output and it always stops at ajax success function. tried pure Javascript - same problem, tried callback with ajax

Comment: @epascarello I see what you mean. I'm pretty sure I have tried it. Gonna try again

Comment: @epascarello I've changed it, so the validation is happening before submitting but I still don't get the (result.result == 1) msg  neither the console output for when I check anything

Comment: @epascarello I've edited it

Comment: What does `actions.php` do? That should be giving a response.

Comment: @PaulT. Unbelievably after checking it a milion times, at the bottom of the actions.php file there was some freak HTML code. No idea how it got there. it seems to have fixed the output issue but i still can't validate it (stop data from sending) and the checkbox questions (question5) behaves strangely. When all is checked I get all the output and when only question5 is unchecked I get nothing. Will add actions.php

Comment: OK, I tried to install and use Komodo IDE (on Linux). The tip is to use column mode: Use Shift + Alt + arrow keys. Use it to select blocks of white space to delete (to decrease indent for the selected lines) and use a zero-width selection and Space to increase. Shift + Tab and Tab seems to have the same effect in Komodo IDE and may in fact be the preferred way, but the block select one is more general and can be used in other editors (though keyboard shortcuts for it varies a lot, e.g. between UltraEdit, Notepad++, Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code and Vim).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for your tips Peter. I will definitely adhere as I want my code to be clean and friendly.As for the problem I've managed to fix it. The problem was with the "implode" function of php (question5). I've only noticed it through the ajax error function!! What a relief. I changed it to a json_encode method and sent my question 5 array that way. Then I did the whole validation through php instead of js and jquery.